# Moving instantiated objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game as a means to learn C#. However, I've run into issues with generating multiple enemies.

First, the cloned enemies do not move down the screen. And second, if the enemies collide with each other it produces an infinite loop of new (spawning) enemies. I figured out part of the movement problem, I need to enable the script on the clones inside Unity, but I am unsure how to "properly" fix it (i.e. non-manually).

Here is the script for the enemies:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform TS;
    public float minSpeed = 3f, maxSpeed = 8f, currentSpeed;
    public float llocation = -9.15f, rlocation = 9.15f, ylocation = 7.65f; //Above visible screen

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        TS = transform; //Cache Transform.

        currentSpeed = Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed); //Randomize enemy speed;
        TS.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (llocation, rlocation), ylocation, 0); //Randomize enemy spawn point.
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        TS.position += (Vector3.down * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //Bring enemy down the screen.
        if (TS.position.y < -5.35f) {
            TS.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range (llocation, rlocation), ylocation, 0);
            currentSpeed = Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
        } //end new spawnpoint and speed.
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.CompareTag("Laser") || collider.CompareTag("Player")) { //Tag is name of prefab.
            //When the laser hits the enemy, destroy the enemy.
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        if (Player.score < 500 || Player.playerLives >= 1) {
            for (int enemies = 0; enemies < 3; enemies++) {
                print("Enemies: " + enemies);
                Vector3 nposition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (llocation, rlocation), ylocation, 0);
                Instantiate(this, nposition, Quaternion.identity);
                //TS.position += (Vector3.down * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code for function "OnTriggerEnter" :

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.CompareTag("Laser") || collider.CompareTag("Player")) { //Tag is name of prefab.
        //When the laser hits the enemy, destroy the enemy.
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    if(collider.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
        if (Player.score < 500 || Player.playerLives >= 1) {
            for (int enemies = 0; enemies < 3; enemies++) {
                print("Enemies: " + enemies);
                Vector3 nposition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (llocation, rlocation), ylocation, 0);
                Instantiate(gameObject, nposition, Quaternion.identity);
                //TS.position += (Vector3.down * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```